# How to correctly unfold an array through the pipeline?

Tags: powershell

PS "unfolds" array when it is passed through the pipeline.
I want to test it using the following test script:

```
$a = @("a", "b", "c")
$a | Write-Host
```

In this case `$a` array unfolds correctly:

```
a
b
c
```

However, when I use my own function

```
Function Do-Something([Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)] $str) {
    Write-Host $str
}

$a | Do-Something
```

the output is:

```
c
```

How to correctly process the array elements through the pipeline in a custom function?

Comment: See [How do I write a PowerShell script that accepts pipeline input?](//stackoverflow.com/a/885627)

Comment: Here's an excellent [blog post by Boe Prox](https://learn-powershell.net/2013/05/07/tips-on-implementing-pipeline-support/) on the topic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> the output is wrong

No, your function definition is "wrong". Change it to:

```
Function Do-Something([Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)] $str) {
    process { Write-Host $str }
}
```

---

An advanced powershell function (one that takes pipeline input), has 3 blocks in it's body: `begin`, `process` and `end`, and looks like this:

```
Function Do-Something {
    param([Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)] $str)

    begin {}
    process {}
    end {}
}
```

The `begin` and `end` blocks will be called *once* each (at the beginning and end, respectively), whereas the `process` block will be invoked once *per input value* bound from the pipeline in between.

When you omit the `begin`, `process` and `end` declarations, the entire body of the function will be interpreted as the `end` block, so your sample function is effectively interpreted as:

```
Function Do-Something {
    param([Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)] $str)

    end {
        Write-Host $str
    }
}
```

Which is why you see that the `Write-Host` cmdlet is only being invoked once, for the very last input value.

Comment: Wrong function definition causes wrong output. I don't see any inconsistency.

Comment: @enkryptor No, the output was completely consistent with the language specification :-P

Comment: This is documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_methods?view=powershell-7.2#input-processing-methods) for those curious

Answer (score 1):

You could also try

```
,$a | Do-Something
```

No need to use the process block in this case.

Comment: To my knowledge, that won't unfold the array. You pass an array of arrays instead. The first array is unfolded, and the second one is passed to the function.

Comment: May be I am completely on the wrong track but something like this should deliver the result that you wished: `function f1 ([Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)][Object]$v)

Comment: (please ignore the first comment - I was too late saving it). May be I am completely on the wrong track but this is not about an array of arrays. Although the PowerShell help states that the comma creates an array with one member putting a comma before an array variable passes all the elements of the array itself. Did you try it?

Comment: Yes I did. It gives "a b c", the same result as `Write-Host $a`. It is **not** the expected output from the Q.

Comment: You are right. Inside the function $a is still an array and the output is that of an array. But if you use `$a | Write-Host` inside the function you would get the same result without having to resort to a process block.

Comment: One last comment: Using the `process` block as suggested by Mathias R. Jensen is from my experience the best practice because you'll get each array element as a single object. Using `Write-Host` is not best practice because it does not output the value through the pipeline.